# How to do inputs in x86 assembly on windows?

Tags: assembly, x86

So I've been trying to do something like the `input()` from python in x86 assembly. It is like, when you run the compiled executable in the console, it prints a prompt (for eg 'give some input: ') and waits till you write something in the console and press enter, then it stores what you typed into a variable or something... I tried many ways but they don't work. Pls suggest.

My current code:

```
_main:
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4

    push    -11
    call    _GetStdHandle@4
    mov     ebx, eax    

    push    0
    lea     eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    (prompt_len - prompt)
    push    prompt
    push    ebx
    call    _WriteFile@20
    
    lea eax, [format]
    push eax
    lea eax, [x_str]
    push eax
    
    ; Call scanf
    call _scanf
    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
```

it prints the prompt but then exits quickly, what should I do.
`prompt` is the prompt. `format db "%d",0`. and `x_str` is the variable i want to store the input in.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the arguments for `scanf` the wrong way round, the format string is the first argument, the one nearest the stack pointer on entry to the function.